# Jquery combobox detect if disabled

Tags: jquery, combobox

I'm working a version of jquery combobox and I need to determine if the combobox is disabled or not...

I tried...

```
alert($('#test').prop('disabled'));
```

but even if I disable $('#test') it still returns false.

Here is a link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frankn/7jf7cngd/105/)

Comment: Because the widget plugin code simply hides `$('#test')` and inserts a different UI. Use the methods of the plugin to check. The `<select>` itself is not disabled...or it wouldn't submit in a form

Comment: If above statement isn't as expected then you need to define your issue in more specific terms.

Comment: @charlietfl no your answer makes sense... I'm still pretty new to jquery programming and need to figure how to use the plugin methods or I'm thinking I should try and disable the <select> itself... need to figure out which is easier and more useful in the long run I guess

Comment: The widget will have ability to check internally...read the docs

Comment: @charlietfl your answer got me thinking... I updated the fiddle with what works for me. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
$('#test').is(':disabled');
```

If is disabled state, it will return true otherwise false.

Comment: So would OP's code. This doesn't do anything different

Comment: It couldn't be, you try alert with the statement, it should give you true if and only you disabled your element.

Comment: The element represented by selector isn't disabled in the first place...check the demo